# javascript xml getElementsByTagName where tag is a number

Tags: javascript, xml

I've had a section of my JavaScript code that's been working fine for a while now to grab values from incoming xml comms, but it has suddenly stopped reporting any found elements by certain tags.  I did some looking and it seems that only tags that are numbers get affected by this, once I switch back to letters everything works great.  Is there some reason why I can't use just numbers?

Javascript Code:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
    x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTaName("VAR");
    alert(x.length); // <- reports 0 when numbers are used as tags
    var dataBack = [];
    for (j=0;j<x.length;j++) {
        dataBack[j] = x[0].getElementsByTagName(x[j])[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    }
    useXMLdata(dataBack);
 }
```

I have tried adding a single letter to my number tags and it magically starts to work.  I'm using this to actually catch the tags, but I'm curious why I can't use only numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements which are only numbers (e.g. `<8>Some content</8>`) do not appear to be valid XML.

The [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/) is pretty turgid, but [section 3.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags) defines start tag naming.  A start tag name must begin with a `NameStartChar` character and then continue with any number of `NameChar` characters.

`NameStartChar` appears to be a subset of `NameChar` which does not include the digits 0-9 among other things.  Therefore a valid tag name cannot begin with a numeric digit.

I doubt your XML will validate if it contains XML elements such as `<8>Something</8>`.  Whether that is the reason that your JavaScript fails I have no idea, but it's reason enough not to structure your XML in that way.

**Edit**

Try plugging the following XML into a [validator](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_validate.asp):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<Root>
  <Child>
    <1xyz>Content</1xyz>
  </Child>
</Root>
```

This gives the error **Invalid element name** for the `<1xyz>` tag.  Even SO doesn't like it hence the lack of syntax highlighting!

Comment: Thanks for the information!  I was curious and that satisfies me, I'll be more careful of tag names in the future.